# Is Grandpa Irrational? Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Grandpa likes iron skillets but not aluminum pans
>
> He likes m&m but not just "m"
>
> He likes Michigan but not Georgia

Why is that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Grandpa

> likes the number 26, but superstitiously dislikes the number 13.

The three examples:

> Iron has atomic number 26, while Aluminum's is 13.
>  **m&m**'s letter positions sum is 26, and **m** is the 13th letter of the alphabet.
>  Michigan was admitted into the US as the 26th state, and Georgia was the 13th of the colonies.

Comment: Bravo again @Tom. I was looking at what else had 26  13 combination. Turns out Latin alphabets are 26 and Hawaiian has 13! But would have been too obvious

Answer (score 14):

With only three examples, this risks being too broad... One possible solution is that Grandpa likes:

> Words/phrases with exactly two "holes" in them.
>
>  *ir**o**n skill**e**ts* (2) vs ***a***luminum **pa**ns (3)
>  *m**&**m* (2) vs *"m"* (0)
>  *Michi**ga**n* (2) vs *G**eo**r**g**i**a*** (4)

Comment: This is a good answer, although the tag is Knowledge and not Pattern — maybe that will help....?

Comment: Very good observation. It always amazes me that there are so many ways to look at these type of puzzles